# Invoking a Web Service via DLL getting this error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, dll

I get this error when invoking my dll with SAP B1 Integration Framework:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'MobiService.AccountsSoap' in the Service Model client configuration
>   section.
>
> This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

But when I invoke the DLL via another .NET application it works.
My app config is set:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://191.211.42.100/MobiVendWSTest/accounts.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AccountsSoap"
            contract="MobiService.AccountsSoap" name="AccountsSoap" />
</client>**
```

Comment: Does SAP B1 Integration Framework use configuration files?  DLLs in and of themselves do not consume configuration files (at least, not out of the box).

Comment: You have to make sure the configuration is in the app.config or web.config used by the application which is using your dll. Probably the configuration of the SAP B1 framework it self.

Comment: SAP B1 Integration Framework uses the DLL config file (app.config) as it is. So when I copy the dll to the use destination I just copy the config file with.

Comment: I use the config file with the dll and the end point is set in my app.config but for some reason it does not seem to pick up the end point. I also have a email notification method int the dll and it picks up settings I set up in the dll. so it should work when my end point is specified in the app.config

Comment: No, because the settings have default values which are compiled into the program and used if the config can not be found. Try changing the config file and you will notice that the new settings are not used. But that's only for the *settings*. The *service configuration* is a totally different story.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the entire service configuration from the DLL's `app.config` to your application's `app.config`, as DLLs can not have their own `app.config`.

The application will read its `app.config` and the DLL will automatically find the settings even though there's no separate config file for it.

Comment: My application configuration file contains the system service Model information where the bindings and client information is automatically set when you add the web service to your projects. this is specified underneath my application setting. @Thorsten Dittmar

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post the `app.config` as a comment!

Comment: Okay, so I have my application configuration file containing all the information about the web service. This is automatically set when adding the web service to the project! @Thorsten

Comment: This is what I understood: You have a DLL project to which you added a service reference to a WCF service. So far so good. Now that you're trying to call a method from the DLL that invokes the call you get an error. If you add the service reference to the DLL project, the `app.config` for the DLL gets modified so the service configuration is added. However, your application's `app.config` does not contain that information. That's why you need to copy it from the DLL's `app.config` to the application's `app.config`. Feel free to edit your question with further info if I'm getting your wrong.

Comment: I only have one `app.config` in my project. When I add new settings or Web Services that file gets edited so I assume that is my application `app.config` ma I correct @Thorsten

Comment: You understand it perfectly, but I still get this error, Please explain the `app.config` and the application `app.config` because I have one `app.config` in my project that holds my DLL settings and information about my Web Service I added @Thorsten

Comment: OK. You have a DLL project, but you need to have an application project that actually *uses* the DLL, right? In *that* application project there also needs to be an `app.config`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so in Busness One Integration Framework I call the dll. Where I specify the `emailnotification.dll` path I will need to also specify `EmailNotification.dll.config` correct ? @Thorsten

Comment: Ahaa, so the application calling the DLL is not under your control! So the answer is: No, the DLL will not read the `EmailNotification.dll.config`. The configuration mechanism only works if the executing application reads the configuration. The easiest in your case would be to manually create the service client configuration in your code instead of relying on a configuration file.

Comment: I have some problems setting the web service end point information via the Web Service object. Maybe I can specify the `app.config` when calling the dll. This should work then ? @Thorsten

Comment: You can try, but I don't think it will work, as the DLL will *not read* the configuration.

Comment: I fixed it via setting the endpoint in code. - Thanks @Thorsten